# Do blini have to be thin?

Tags: language, pancakes

In case you're wondering, Blin (or Блин) is just Pancake in Russian.

It was given by [my favorite YouTuber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UOowIxfX88) that these pancakes have to be thin to be a proper blin. Is this true?

Comment: Questions need to stand on their own, not be entirely reliant on an external source - otherwise if that source ever disappears, so does the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be more of a linguistic question to me.
It depends on who you ask. In the region where I live: not necessarily, both the American style and French crêpe style pancakes are sometimes called "блин" and "блинчики" (little pancakes).

But for a lot of people it's only the French thin ones. And they call the other one "оладушки". (Read: oladushki)
It's not exactly defined by region as much as simply what you're used to.

Also: the word is also a curse word, although a very childish one. The English version might be 'crap', I  think.

Comment: True. "Pancake" is not a reasonable translation of "блин". The variety I am familiar with are yeast risen and so not similar to crepes except in thinness. It's like asking how to translate "Spaghetti" into English. You can describe it but there isn't a translation.

Comment: @Sobachatina - reminds me of a trip to Venice. The menus are provided in several languages, English being actually the least useful. "Meat sauce with paste" (yes, past***e***) does not really adequately describe 'spaghetti bolognese' or any of the other dishes that could be over-translated into the same description. I had to read the Italian to know what I was ordering, even though I don't speak Italian ;)

Comment: Yes, but it is not really "crap", but rather the family-friendly form of "блять" (blyat) which you might already know.

Comment: I meant that it would be used in the same context as the English speaking would use 'crap'. When you drop something or miss your bus for example.